# Pass array to shader

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, opengl-es, webgl, shader

I create my array this.kernel: it hast 48 elements and I want to pass it to my fragment shader.

When i call

```
 gl.uniform3fv(gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "kernel"), 16, this.kernel);
```

kernel is defined in my shader:

```
uniform vec3 kernel[16];
```

I get an error for not enough arguments.
I already looked up the specification etc, but don't find my problem -.-

```
void glUniform3fv(  GLint  location, GLsizei  count, const GLfloat * value);
```

Thanks for help

€: I converted this.kernel to a float32array but I still have this error.

€2: error in Chrome: not enough arguments

in Firefox: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `this.kernel` needs to be a Float32Array of length 48 (=3*16). You cannot use an array of vec3s.

Also the count is not used in WebGL. The function is (from [WebGL Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/))

```
void uniform3fv(WebGLUniformLocation? location, Float32Array v);
```

Example usage:

```
gl.uniform3fv(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "colors"), new Float32Array([0,1,2,3,4,5]));
```

See a complete example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mortennobel/URvtx/

Comment: AH ok. I changed my array this.kernel to this.kernel = new Float32Array(this.kernel); The length is exactly 48 long.
Just to be clear I meant the kernel in my shader is a vec3

Still getting the error not enough arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I experimented so much but it seems I forgot this variation.